# Midrash talpiyot in english on the web?

Tags: midrash

I am looking for an English version of Midrash talpiyot. But the best I could do was just view these versions https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/011261779. The version with more pages (and I believe this one is more complete) is this one https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hwmfz7&view=1up&seq=1. The only difficulty is that the university I work for is not a partner of hathitrust.org and so I can't download the full document.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I don't see that there's an English translation in either of your links. Are you sure there's one available?

Comment: This is something that I could not imagine being translated

Comment: That is only as English as far as the transliterated title is concerned

Comment: The full text of the first link is viewable for free, no membership required, @https://hdl.handle.net/2027/wu.89084483742 . It does not contain an English translation or any English text at all